# Creating files using java.nio.file Functionality

Tags: java, path

I was reading the oracle to understand how to create files using Path in  java.nio.file Functionality instead of java.io.File Functionality 
and this is the sample code:

```
Path file = ...;
   try {
   // Create the empty file with default permissions, etc.
   Files.createFile(file);
    } catch (FileAlreadyExistsException x) {
    System.err.format("file named %s" +
    " already exists%n", file);
   } catch (IOException x) {
    // Some other sort of failure, such as permissions.
   System.err.format("createFile error: %s%n", x);
  }
```

But what is in the ...; space? what should I type there?

Comment: Path file = Paths.get("myfile.txt");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Paths.get`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get(java.net.URI)) produce a [`Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html) object.

```
Path path = Paths.get("src/main/resources/question.txt");
```

Or:

```
Path path = Paths.get("src","main","resources","question.txt");
```

A [`Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html) object is a hierarchical representation of the path on a system to the file or directory. The `java.nio.file.Path` interface is the primary entry point for working with the NIO 2 API.

The easiest way to create a Path Object is to use the `java.nio.files.Paths` factory class. The class has a pair of static `get()` method which can be used to obtain a reference to a file or directory. The methods accept either a string, or a sequence of strings (which it will join to form a path) as parameters. A `java.nio.file.Path` , like a `File`, may refer to either an absolute or relative path within the file system.